# load time binding vs execution time binding

Tags: operating-system

Good evening!
After some research, I got to know there is three types of binding :

1. compile time binding
2. load time binding
3. execution time binding

I can clearly see the reason for avoiding using compile time binding.
However, I'm pretty not sure which one among remaining two policy is the better one, and so used in modern OS.

Any clear advice for me?
I appreciate your time.